# ValueError: array length does not match index length

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, kaggle

I am practicing for contests like kaggle and I have been trying to use XGBoost and am trying to get myself familiar with python 3rd party libraries like pandas and numpy.

I have been reviewing scripts from this particular competition called the Santander Customer Satisfaction Classification and I have been modifying different forked scripts in order to experiment on them.

Here is one modified script through which I am trying to implement XGBoost:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cross_validation as cv
import xgboost as xgb

df_train = pd.read_csv("/Users/pavan7vasan/Desktop/Machine_Learning/Project Datasets/Santander_Customer_Satisfaction/train.csv")
df_test  = pd.read_csv("/Users/pavan7vasan/Desktop/Machine_Learning/Project Datasets/Santander_Customer_Satisfaction/test.csv")   

df_train = df_train.replace(-999999,2)

id_test = df_test['ID']
y_train = df_train['TARGET'].values
X_train = df_train.drop(['ID','TARGET'], axis=1).values
X_test = df_test.drop(['ID'], axis=1).values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cv.train_test_split(X_train, y_train, random_state=1301, test_size=0.4)

clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic',
                missing=9999999999,
                max_depth = 7,
                n_estimators=200,
                learning_rate=0.1, 
                nthread=4,
                subsample=1.0,
                colsample_bytree=0.5,
                min_child_weight = 3,
                reg_alpha=0.01,
                seed=7)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds=50, eval_metric="auc", eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)])
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)

print("Cross validating and checking the score...")
scores = cv.cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train) 
'''
test = []
result = []
for each in id_test:
    test.append(each)
for each in y_pred[:,1]:
    result.append(each)

print len(test)
print len(result)
'''
submission = pd.DataFrame({"ID":id_test, "TARGET":y_pred[:,1]})
#submission = pd.DataFrame({"ID":test, "TARGET":result})
submission.to_csv("submission_XGB_Pavan.csv", index=False)
```

Here is the stacktrace :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pavan7vasan/Documents/workspace/Machine_Learning_Project/Kaggle/XG_Boost.py", line 45, in <module>
submission = pd.DataFrame({"ID":id_test, "TARGET":y_pred[:,1]})
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 214, in __init__
mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 341, in _init_dict
dtype=dtype)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4798, in _arrays_to_mgr
index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4856, in extract_index
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: array length 30408 does not match index length 75818
```

I have tried solutions based on my searches for different solutions, but I am not able to figure out what the mistake is. What is it that I have gone wrong in? Please let me know

Comment: Where's your traceback? Provide a minimal script that anyone else can run (e.g. without the external csv data) and we can help you better

Comment: you're defining `X_test` twice, this might be causing the problem

Comment: @tdihp : oh i totally forgot!!!  Thank you for the reminder, will update it now

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you defining `X_test` twice as @maxymoo mentioned. First you defined it as

```
X_test = df_test.drop(['ID'], axis=1).values
```

And then you redefine that with:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cv.train_test_split(X_train, y_train, random_state=1301, test_size=0.4)
```

Which means now `X_test` have size equal to `0.4*len(X_train)`. Then after:

```
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

you've got predictions for that part of `X_train` and you trying to create dataframe with that and initial `id_test` which has length of the original `X_test`.
You could use `X_fit` and `X_eval` in `train_test_split` and not hide initial `X_train` and `X_test` because for your `cross_validation` you also has different `X_train` which means you'll not get right answer or you `cv` would be inaccurate with public/private score.