# TensorFlow - ValueError: Array length 10000 does not match index length 12000

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to lstms and tensorflow. I'm using 2 data sets containing 12000 records in each (training_set = 12000 and test_set = 12000). When I run model I get the following error.

```
ValueError: array length 10000 does not match index length 12000
```

In my code I have created the training and validation sets as below.

```
# Creating the training and validation sets
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(train_pad, train.sentiment, test_size = 0.84, random_state = 2)
x_test = test_pad
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/Currie32/Movie-Reviews-Sentiment/blob/master/RNN_movie_reviews.py) tutorial and code to create mine. Can someone please help me and let me know how to modify the code and resolve this error.

Thanks in advance

please find the full code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import nltk, re, time
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from string import punctuation
from collections import defaultdict
from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from collections import namedtuple

#get data
train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")


train.head()
test.head()


print(train.shape)
print("-------------------------------")
print(test.shape)


print(train.isnull().sum())
print(test.isnull().sum())


train_clean = []
for post in train.post:
    train_clean.append(post)


test_clean = []
for post in test.post:
    test_clean.append(post)

# Tokenize the reviews
all_reviews = train_clean + test_clean
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(all_reviews)
print("Fitting is complete.")

train_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_clean)
print("train_seq is complete.")

test_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_clean)
print("test_seq is complete")



# Find the number of unique tokens
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print("Words in index: %d" % len(word_index))


# Find the length of reviews
lengths = []
for post in train_seq:
    lengths.append(len(post))

for post in test_seq:
    lengths.append(len(post))

# Create a dataframe so that the values can be inspected
lengths = pd.DataFrame(lengths, columns=['counts'])


lengths.counts.describe()


# Pad and truncate the questions so that they all have the same length.
max_review_length = 200

train_pad = pad_sequences(train_seq, maxlen = max_review_length)
print("train_pad is complete.")

test_pad = pad_sequences(test_seq, maxlen = max_review_length)
print("test_pad is complete.")


# Creating the training and validation sets
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(train_pad, train.sentiment, test_size = 0.5, random_state = 2)
x_test = test_pad



# Inspect the shape of the data
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_valid.shape)
print(x_test.shape)


def get_batches(x, y, batch_size):
    '''Create the batches for the training and validation data'''
    n_batches = len(x)//batch_size
    x, y = x[:n_batches*batch_size], y[:n_batches*batch_size]
    for ii in range(0, len(x), batch_size):
        yield x[ii:ii+batch_size], y[ii:ii+batch_size]


def get_test_batches(x, batch_size):
    '''Create the batches for the testing data'''
    n_batches = len(x)//batch_size
    x = x[:n_batches*batch_size]
    for ii in range(0, len(x), batch_size):
        yield x[ii:ii+batch_size]


def build_rnn(n_words, embed_size, batch_size, lstm_size, num_layers,
              dropout, learning_rate, multiple_fc, fc_units):
    '''Build the Recurrent Neural Network'''

    tf.reset_default_graph()

    # Declare placeholders we'll feed into the graph
    with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
        inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='inputs')

    with tf.name_scope('labels'):
        labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='labels')

    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')

    # Create the embeddings
    with tf.name_scope("embeddings"):
        embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((n_words, embed_size), -1, 1))
        embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, inputs)

    def lstm_cell(lstm_size, keep_prob):
        lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
        drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
        return drop

    # Build the RNN layers
    with tf.name_scope("RNN_layers"):
        #lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
        #lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(name='basic_lstm_cell')(lstm_size)

        #lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(lstm_size)
        #drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
        #cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([drop] * num_layers)
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell(lstm_size, keep_prob) for _ in range(num_layers)])

    # Set the initial state
    with tf.name_scope("RNN_init_state"):
        initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

    # Run the data through the RNN layers
    with tf.name_scope("RNN_forward"):
        outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, embed,
                                                 initial_state=initial_state)

    # Create the fully connected layers
    with tf.name_scope("fully_connected"):

        # Initialize the weights and biases
        weights = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1)
        biases = tf.zeros_initializer()

        dense = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs[:, -1],
                                                  num_outputs = fc_units,
                                                  activation_fn = tf.sigmoid,
                                                  weights_initializer = weights,
                                                  biases_initializer = biases)
        dense = tf.contrib.layers.dropout(dense, keep_prob)

        # Depending on the iteration, use a second fully connected layer
        if multiple_fc == True:
            dense = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(dense,
                                                      num_outputs = fc_units,
                                                      activation_fn = tf.sigmoid,
                                                      weights_initializer = weights,
                                                      biases_initializer = biases)
            dense = tf.contrib.layers.dropout(dense, keep_prob)

    # Make the predictions
    with tf.name_scope('predictions'):
        predictions = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(dense,
                                                        num_outputs = 1,
                                                        activation_fn=tf.sigmoid,
                                                        weights_initializer = weights,
                                                        biases_initializer = biases)
        tf.summary.histogram('predictions', predictions)

    # Calculate the cost
    with tf.name_scope('cost'):
        cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
        tf.summary.scalar('cost', cost)

    # Train the model
    with tf.name_scope('train'):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    # Determine the accuracy
    with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
        correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.cast(tf.round(predictions), tf.int32), labels)
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
        tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)

    # Merge all of the summaries
    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

    # Export the nodes
    export_nodes = ['inputs', 'labels', 'keep_prob', 'initial_state', 'final_state','accuracy',
                    'predictions', 'cost', 'optimizer', 'merged']
    Graph = namedtuple('Graph', export_nodes)
    local_dict = locals()
    graph = Graph(*[local_dict[each] for each in export_nodes])

    return graph


def train(model, epochs, log_string):
    '''Train the RNN'''

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        # Used to determine when to stop the training early
        valid_loss_summary = []

        # Keep track of which batch iteration is being trained
        iteration = 0

        print()
        print("Training Model: {}".format(log_string))

        train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs/3/train/{}'.format(log_string), sess.graph)
        valid_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs/3/valid/{}'.format(log_string))

        for e in range(epochs):
            state = sess.run(model.initial_state)

            # Record progress with each epoch
            train_loss = []
            train_acc = []
            val_acc = []
            val_loss = []

            with tqdm(total=len(x_train)) as pbar:
                for _, (x, y) in enumerate(get_batches(x_train, y_train, batch_size), 1):
                    feed = {model.inputs: x,
                            model.labels: y[:, None],
                            model.keep_prob: dropout,
                            model.initial_state: state}
                    summary, loss, acc, state, _ = sess.run([model.merged,
                                                             model.cost,
                                                             model.accuracy,
                                                             model.final_state,
                                                             model.optimizer],
                                                            feed_dict=feed)

                    # Record the loss and accuracy of each training batch
                    train_loss.append(loss)
                    train_acc.append(acc)

                    # Record the progress of training
                    train_writer.add_summary(summary, iteration)

                    iteration += 1
                    pbar.update(batch_size)

            # Average the training loss and accuracy of each epoch
            avg_train_loss = np.mean(train_loss)
            avg_train_acc = np.mean(train_acc)

            val_state = sess.run(model.initial_state)
            with tqdm(total=len(x_valid)) as pbar:
                for x, y in get_batches(x_valid, y_valid, batch_size):
                    feed = {model.inputs: x,
                            model.labels: y[:, None],
                            model.keep_prob: 1,
                            model.initial_state: val_state}
                    summary, batch_loss, batch_acc, val_state = sess.run([model.merged,
                                                                          model.cost,
                                                                          model.accuracy,
                                                                          model.final_state],
                                                                         feed_dict=feed)

                    # Record the validation loss and accuracy of each epoch
                    val_loss.append(batch_loss)
                    val_acc.append(batch_acc)
                    pbar.update(batch_size)

            # Average the validation loss and accuracy of each epoch
            avg_valid_loss = np.mean(val_loss)
            avg_valid_acc = np.mean(val_acc)
            valid_loss_summary.append(avg_valid_loss)

            # Record the validation data's progress
            valid_writer.add_summary(summary, iteration)

            # Print the progress of each epoch
            print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(e, epochs),
                  "Train Loss: {:.3f}".format(avg_train_loss),
                  "Train Acc: {:.3f}".format(avg_train_acc),
                  "Valid Loss: {:.3f}".format(avg_valid_loss),
                  "Valid Acc: {:.3f}".format(avg_valid_acc))

            # Stop training if the validation loss does not decrease after 3 epochs
            if avg_valid_loss > min(valid_loss_summary):
                print("No Improvement.")
                stop_early += 1
                if stop_early == 3:
                    break

            # Reset stop_early if the validation loss finds a new low
            # Save a checkpoint of the model
            else:
                print("New Record!")
                stop_early = 0
                checkpoint = "/home/sm/Documents/ML/sentiment_{}.ckpt".format(log_string)
                saver.save(sess, checkpoint)


# The default parameters of the model
n_words = len(word_index)
embed_size = 300
batch_size = 250
lstm_size = 128
num_layers = 2
dropout = 0.5
learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 10
multiple_fc = False
fc_units = 256


# Train the model with the desired tuning parameters
for lstm_size in [64,128]:
    for multiple_fc in [True, False]:
        for fc_units in [128, 256]:
            log_string = 'ru={},fcl={},fcu={}'.format(lstm_size,
                                                      multiple_fc,
                                                      fc_units)
            model = build_rnn(n_words = n_words,
                              embed_size = embed_size,
                              batch_size = batch_size,
                              lstm_size = lstm_size,
                              num_layers = num_layers,
                              dropout = dropout,
                              learning_rate = learning_rate,
                              multiple_fc = multiple_fc,
                              fc_units = fc_units)
            train(model, epochs, log_string)


# # Make the Predictions

def make_predictions(lstm_size, multiple_fc, fc_units, checkpoint):
    '''Predict the sentiment of the testing data'''

    # Record all of the predictions
    all_preds = []

    model = build_rnn(n_words = n_words,
                      embed_size = embed_size,
                      batch_size = batch_size,
                      lstm_size = lstm_size,
                      num_layers = num_layers,
                      dropout = dropout,
                      learning_rate = learning_rate,
                      multiple_fc = multiple_fc,
                      fc_units = fc_units)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        # Load the model
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint)
        test_state = sess.run(model.initial_state)
        for _, x in enumerate(get_test_batches(x_test, batch_size), 1):
            feed = {model.inputs: x,
                    model.keep_prob: 1,
                    model.initial_state: test_state}
            predictions = sess.run(model.predictions, feed_dict=feed)
            for pred in predictions:
                all_preds.append(float(pred))

    return all_preds



checkpoint1 = "/home/sm/Documents/ML/sentiment_ru=128,fcl=False,fcu=256.ckpt"
checkpoint2 = "/home/sm/Documents/ML/sentiment_ru=128,fcl=False,fcu=128.ckpt"
checkpoint3 = "/home/sm/Documents/ML/sentiment_ru=64,fcl=True,fcu=256.ckpt"


# Make predictions using the best 3 models
predictions1 = make_predictions(128, False, 256, checkpoint1)
predictions2 = make_predictions(128, False, 128, checkpoint2)
predictions3 = make_predictions(64, True, 256, checkpoint3)

# Average the best three predictions
predictions_combined = (pd.DataFrame(predictions1) + pd.DataFrame(predictions2) + pd.DataFrame(predictions3))/3

def write_submission(predictions, string):
    '''write the predictions to a csv file'''
    submission = pd.DataFrame(data={"id":test["id"], "sentiment":predictions})
    submission.to_csv("submission_{}.csv".format(string), index=False, quoting=3)

write_submission(predictions1, "ru=128,fcl=False,fcu=256")
write_submission(predictions2, "ru=128,fcl=False,fcu=128")
write_submission(predictions3, "ru=64,fcl=True,fcu=256")
write_submission(predictions_combined.ix[:,0], "combined")
```

Comment: Try providing some information regarding the datasets and the code used to parse it.

Comment: I used panda to parse the data. `train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")`

Comment: I've updated the question with the full code. Could you please check and let me know how solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to have a `test_size` of `0.84`? It doesn't make sense. I suppose you meant the size of the validation set to be `0.16` and training set size to be `0.84`, didn't you? Because of the above reason, the training set size would've become smaller and hence the error maybe. But of course not enough information to figure the error out.

And also please check whether you have assigned another dataframe to `x_test` somewhere else, as this error might come from multi assigning. Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063350/valueerror-array-length-does-not-match-index-length).

Comment: I've updated the question with the full code. Could you please check and let me know how solve it.

Comment: What dataset are you using? If you could give me a link to the dataset I'd be able to have a go with this code.

Comment: Thank you. I got the data set from https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/data . The dataset has around 25000 records. I didn't use the whole thing. Took only 1200 records from each (labeledTrainData.tsv and testData.tsv) to check the code.

Comment: What line does the error come? I ran it with the full dataset and it runs like a charm. I have trained it for several epochs as well. Only thing I had to change is to replace the key `post` in your code with `review`. You're getting the error probably because you take a part of the dataset. And I don't know how you take a part or where the error happens to make a comment.

Comment: This is the error I get. File "lx.py", line 560, in <module>
    write_submission(predictions1, "ru=128,fcl=False,fcu=256")
  File "lx.py", line 554, in write_submission
    submission = pd.DataFrame(data={"id":test["id"], "sentiment":predictions})

Comment: Solved it. Problem was batch size should be a multiple of the length of the datasets. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Well it should not to be honest. Batch size doesn't have anything to do with train set size. Glad somehow it worked.